# É possível executar um PHP diferente em determinada pasta?

Tags: php, apache

Eu estou com um problema:

O servidor utiliza o PHP 5.3, que é muito antigo, mas não pode ser alterado. Tenho um script que requer o PHP 5.4 +, é o websocket Ratchet. É possível instalar um PHP separado para ser utilizado somente na pasta em que se encontra este script?

Comment: Talvez isto ajude: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85543/compiling-php-and-installing-it-under-one-directory

Comment: Não seria mais simples modificar o código? ou você utiliza alguma coisa que não tem como contornar como 5.3?

Comment: Não tem como contornar. No caso é o websocket Ratchet que não funcionou no servidor por conta do mesmo ser o 5.3

Comment: Falar na pergunta que o script é o Ratchet pode salvar seu tempo ;)

Comment: Obrigado, alterei lá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem como instalar mais de uma versão no mesmo servidor sim.

Depois de instalar as duas versões do PHP, na configuração do Apache, no `httpf.conf` você pode configurar uma extensão para cada versão:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php4 .php4
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php5
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php # the default
```

Também é possivel fazer com que uma pasta inteira utilize uma versão especifica alterando o `.htaccess`, na pasta que quer rodar em uma versão diferente especificando a versão desejada.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php4 .php
```

Fonte:
https://serverfault.com/questions/85385/running-php4-and-php5-along-side-each-other